# Distance matrix quota request not increasing

Tags: google-api, quota, rate-limiting

I am getting rate limited in Google Distance Matrix API. I have requested to increase distance matrix quota hits, my billing is enabled but than also it not increasing request limit. We have filled the form and we received the email. I am not able to proceed further

Comment: Happened also to me, I've had an outage of 45 min. It's unclear, and totally unfair from them. I ended up having a backup plan with Here Maps.

Answer (score -1):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/?hl=fr), each query sent to the Distance Matrix API is limited by the number of allowed elements, where the number of origins times the number of destinations defines the number of elements.

The Distance Matrix API has the following limits in place:

**Users of the free API:**

1. 100 elements per query.
2. 100 elements per 10 seconds.
3. 2500 elements per 24 hour period.

**Maps for Business customers:**

1. 625 elements per query.
2. 1000 elements per 10 seconds.
3. 100000 elements per 24 hour period.

Maps API for Business customers can purchase additional quota by contacting their Google Enterprise Sales Account Manager.

Comment: Rishi thanks for response but using this i enable billing and updated quota for distance matrix, but it not showing increased limits. I wanted to know how we can see that updated limits.

Comment: You might have to contact your Google Enterprise Sales Account Manager